# Jquery- dialog is not running my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where values are filled based on a sql query. The values populate in the dialog box but when I click on a record, its not running my function. I want my function to only select the record id I have clicked on.For now I have put an alert in the function just to see if my function works and its not showing anything. My onClick = "addlink();" is not working.

```
function addreferral()
{
  $.getJSON('libs/getsoldreferrals.php', function(data) {
  $('#soldlist tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();

$.each(data, function(key, val)
 {
  $('#soldlist').append('<tr><td><span id="myreferral" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick = "addlink();" >'+val.id +'</span></td><td></td><td>' + val.office + '</td><td></td><td>'+val.clientdetails+'</td><td></td><td>'+val.buyerorseller+'</td><td></td><td></td><td>'+val.address+'</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'+'<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>'+'<tr><td></td></tr>');
});

    $('#soldlist tr').first().after();


});


 var dialog, form
window.addlink = function addlink() {
        alert("Hello"); 
}

    dialog = $( "#dialog-form-referral" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      height: 450,
      width: 800,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },

    });
```

Comment: you are passing the return value from addlink to the onclick handler try using onclick="addlink" also the "onClick" needs to be "onclick"

Comment: Not related to question - But - Logical Error here: .each(data, function(key, val) - You are creating more than one <span> with the same id = "myreferral" - In HTML your id must be unique inside the same page -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You forgot the closing quotation mark in your style tag.

Change the Markup of your span to the below:

```
<span id="myreferral" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick = "addlink();">
```

Pretty sure that should do it.

Comment: Edit your answer to show the HTML - Select the HTML and Ctrl + K

Answer (score 0):

Try with onclick (small C), and not onClick. Also, try not to mix JavaScript with HTML.

HTH's
Stanko.